# BIT-AND operation on negative integers

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

In MATLAB R2011b it is not possible to process bit-and operation if any of numbers is negative. In Java it would be something like: `-25 & 15 = 7`. How is it possible to get something similar in MATLAB?
Tried to convert to `uint32` before operation, but `uint32(-25) = 0` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`bitand`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html#bthbon-21) operation:

```
intout = bitand(-25, 7, 'int32')
```

On R2011b, `-25` is bit-wise equivalent to `(2^32)-25` if you consider `uint32`. So you can try:

```
intout = int32((2^32 - 25) & 7)
```

Comment: `Error using bitand
Inputs must be non-negative integers. `
That is what I'm talking about. =)

Comment: I edited my answer to add ``'int32'`` as the type. Please confirm that it works :)

Comment: Sorry, but this function was introduced only since Matlab 2012b, in 2011b it has only two input arguments. =)

Comment: Edited again. I don't have any Matlab available to test though :/